# Can't turn off or restart

Tags: 10.10, shutdown

I'm having problems restarting or turning of ubuntu 10.10 on a samsung r560. I had no problems with previous ubuntu versions.

When turning off, ubuntu stays forever in the purple screen with 4 dots.
When restartig, I get

```
init: Disconnectded from system bus
init: dbus main process (752) killed by TERM signal

nm-dispatcher.action: Cought signal 15, shutting down...
modem-manager: Cought signal 15, shutting down...
```

The laptop does not shut down after this.

Comment: tried sudo reboot, did not help. this time I got stuck on the back screen that says ubuntu 10.10 and displays .... under it.

Comment: Have you tried sudo halt ?

Comment: Do you have any mapped network drives in your /etc/fstab?  If so, and you connect to those via WIFI, this is a known bug (but usually also results in a CIFS error, which I don't see in your output).

Comment: I deleted all mapped drives from /etc/fstab but its still the same. I connect to internet via wifi, but I do not connect to any devices this way. I usually have an external hdd attached (usb) + mouse (usb), but I tried without it, same problem. Also, the output is not always like this. Its different every time. One thing I noticed is that if I press "escape", I get to black screen with blinking _ at the top. if I press escape one more time I get to the purple ubuntu screen again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my issue was that rabbit-mq server was stopping me from restarting. so to actually halt I need to

```
sudo service rabbitmq-server stop
sudo halt
```

I just made an alias for it while this issue is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

In terminal type **sudo reboot** or  **sudo halt** to halt your system

For shutting down instantly,

`sudo shutdown -P now`
     or
`sudo poweroff`
     or
`sudo su && init 0`

**[Also See this thread](http://wwww.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1466589&highlight=shutdown+button+work)**

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an external storage device installed on the computer? Try removing first before shutting down.

I found this http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1603642
Not sure if it applies to your situation. This one is a wireless issue.

Comment: Thanks you your attempts, but these suggestions did not drive me to the solution to this problem. Is there any log (or can I set up one) for what goes on on this shutdown command?